# Non-zero diagonal through permutation of rows  

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm looking for a reference of the following statement (which can easily be proved by Laplace's formula and induction):

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with
>   identity and let $A$ be an invertible
>   matrix over $R$. Then there is a
>   permutation matrix $P$ such that the
>   diagonal of $PA$ has no zero.

**Edit:** Of course, $R$ has to be a domain to make the arguments (formula of Leibniz or Laplace) work. Futhermore, it's sufficient to require $det(A) \neq 0$ (instead of $A$ being invertible).

Comment: I'm hoping you won't find a reference of that statement, since it is false. (Consider the 1x1 matrix over the zero ring.)

Comment: Doesn't a ring with identity have at least two elements?

Comment: No, Tony. Otherwise algebra would be swamped in statements like "if $I$ is an ideal of $R$, then $R/I$ is a ring or zero".

Comment: @Ricky: I assume that the identity isn't zero and still hope for a reference. 

Comment: I don't know of a reference, but you can also appeal to the determinant formula as a sum of (permuted) products for a shorter proof.  Then you may not need a reference.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.05.05

Comment: On a related note, if A is invertible (the determinant is nonzero) and there is a zero in every row and in every column, one can get at most (n-1) zeros on the diagonal of PAQ in general even allowing for permutation matrices P and Q.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.05.05

Comment: Oops. in the above, A should be a square matrix of order n.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.05.05

Comment: @Gerhard: Isn't the matrix $$(0,1) $$ $$(1,0)$$ a counterexample for your 2. comment ?


Comment: I think I stated it poorly.  More specifically, for the class of 0-1 nxn matrices A such that A is invertible, and such that A has a zero in every row and a zero in every column, there are examples of such A where PAQ has at most (n-1) zeros on the diagonal, where P and Q are allowed to range over all nxn permutation matrices.  So your example is a counterexample to the poor statement, and says nothing about the (hopefully correctly formulated) statement above.  If I fixed n to be 2 (or 3) however, then the statement above is false. Gerhard "Hope It's Right This Time" Paseman, 2011.05.05

Comment: if I needed to use such a statement, I would just say that "it is easy to show by induction on the size of A that..."

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'll do it this way (by referring to the Leibniz formula as proposed by Gerhard above). 

Answer (score 3):

There is a strictly stronger fact about matrices:

> Given $A\in{\bf M}_n(R)$, the following statements are equivalent.

- There exists a permutation matrix $P$ such that the diagonal of $PA$ has no zero.
- If an $m\times p$-block of $A$ is mades of zeroes, then $m+p\le n$.

Comment: And it's called Hall's marriage theorem.

Comment: @darij, I'd rather say it can be proved using Hall's Marriage Theorem, or any of a number of other theorems equivalent to Hall's, including one, by Konig, that goes back at least 20 years before Hall, and was stated specifically in the context of matrices. 